# How to read url link in pdf using shell script?

Tags: shell, scripting, pdf

I have a chrome bookmark export file in pdf format with hyperlinks to news article, blogs in the internet. I want to write a shell script to parse this file and save the content of each hyperlink (i.e, article, blogs etc) into their respective new pdf file in my local machine.
Any thoughts and quirks is highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pdfgrep`, parse the lines to a new file, and convert the new file to pdf.

https://gitlab.com/pdfgrep/pdfgrep

Comment: The [`pdfgrep`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/pdfgrep) is available on debian through `apt`.